# How to activate and open my app as soon as I unlock my screen in iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm managing few iOS devices, so I want to create a app to add security feature like collecting the user information from the user like UserID to track which user is currently using the device .

**Desired output:**

So I want to trigger my app as soon as a user unlock the device and without giving the details the user should not able to access the home screen of the Device.

Is it possible to do it with any framework in iOS without Jailbreak ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible. iOS does not allows application to manage device with it self. Application should work in the pre given area which is called Sandbox. So its not possible to handle the entire device and you can not check it that who is using the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you should look to Mobile Device Management solutions and rather go that route. You could also look at [apple's business solutions](https://www.apple.com/business/dep/).